# Whitespace instead of symbol '+' in QNetworkRequest

Tags: json, qt, qnetworkrequest

I try to make a JSON object with Qt. I have a floating value: `1.49329e+22`

When I add that to a JSON :

```
jsonObject.insert("lat", QJsonValue((double)metrology->lat));
```

on a server, I get:

```
"lat": 1.4932864507649251e 22
```

What is that whitespace? Because of that whitespace I get an invalid JSON. What's wrong?

**Added:**
I realised that the problem is not in JSON object, it is how `QNetworkRequest` sends data to server. When some string contains symbol '+', it is not displayed on the server. But if I am trying to send to the same server from other service (python's request for example), the symbol '+' is successfully displayed.

How can I send '+' symbol with Qt?

Comment: What do you see if you look a the json value before sending it to the server ?

Comment: `Json vale:  QJsonValue(double, 1.49329e+22)`

Comment: But, on server I see value with namespace...

Comment: I mean the JSON string, JSON is a text format.

Comment: QJsonObject({"alt":24388,"hdop":108,"lat":4.3602962131274737e+21,"lon":9.0156637702406348e+21,"number":99,"sat_seen":188,"sat_used":95,"unixtime":1664245948,"vdop":99})

Comment: hm...whitespace appears only when json string has symbol '+'

Comment: What is you server ?

Comment: python3/django. I just print incoming post data from request.

Comment: You could have a problem in the encoding of your request. Could you add the full content of the request in the question ?